# spotify apps javascript crossfading

Tags: spotify, spotify-queue

How to achieve crossfading on a Spotify javascript based app?

I'm creating a temp playlist and adding songs to it on the fly, the added song plays but doesn't crossfade.

EDIT: I guess the real question is how to cause Spotify to do a refresh of the play queue. the added songs get added to the visible play queue only on the track change, which makes it not crossfade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no programmatic access to crossfading in a spotify app (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/f19ff300f8.html)
However, if the user has crossfading enabled (Settings->Playback->Crossfade tracks) and the model.Player is playing from a context with multiple tracks (like a Playlist or Album) then crossfading should kick in. 
The caveat here is that you have to have the next song in the playlist added early-on enough so that the client has time to recognize the change in the playlist. One way to verify if you're adding this in time is to ensure the 'Play Queue' shows that it will play the next song in your playlist.

Comment: in my tests it worked so that it refreshed the queue so that you would have to know the songs at least one song in advance or the crossfading to kick in... this was a while back though.